# didReceiveRemoteNotification callback is fired automatically withuout user taps on the notification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am integrating firebase push notification in my app.In latest version of iOS it works fine.But in low version of iOS i am having some problems.

In low version of iOS didReceiveRemoteNotification callback is fired automatically without user taps on the notification.

In low version iOS automatically called without user tap Notification

```
[AnyHashable("notification"): {
body = “body text”;
e = 1;
sound = default;
sound2 = default;
title = “title here”;
}, AnyHashable("from”):2343434, AnyHashable("a_data"): ****, AnyHashable("collapse_key"): com.***.****]
```

latest iOS version after user tab the Notification

```
[AnyHashable("a_data"):****, AnyHashable("aps"): {
alert =     {
    body = "body";
    title = "title";
};
sound = default;
}, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): ******]
```

Here is my code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

    // Print full message.
    print("user t \(userInfo)")

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    print(userInfo)

    let aps = userInfo["aps"] as! [String: AnyObject]
    let alert = aps["alert"] as! [String: AnyObject]
    let eventTitle : String = alert["title"] as! String? ?? "Title"
    print(alert["title"] ?? "Title")

}

// This method will be called when app received push notifications in foreground
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

Hope you understand my problem.
How to solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the application running in Foreground Mode or active ?

Comment: yes  running in Foreground

Comment: Okay when its in running mode it will directly invoke this delegate you need to handle this by alert.

Comment: check the application mode in the didReceiveRemoteNotification method if the running/active then show alert. Otherwise dont do anything its only for lower version on ios

Comment: ok fine.Then how to handle conflict in userInfo data in lower and higher version ?

Comment: I am hoping you got a proper suggestion :)

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification called only when you are using lower version of iOS but if you are using higher one this delegate is not called as you are using UNUserNotification so the UNUserNotificationDelegates will be called.

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification callback is fired till the user taps on the notification in higher version of iOS.when user tap the notification i am getting   AnyHashable("aps") in UserInfo but in lower version i am getting AnyHashable("notification").....Hope u understand my problem....so my app will crash in low version of iOS

Comment: ohh got that you need to handle them separately because its issue of firebase. it gives the payload differently.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45220425/5175709). What you're seeing is the **expected** behavior. For +iOS10 upon arrival of *any* remote notification you will get that callback.